# How to remove rows with empty column values in multiple .csv files

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to remove every row in multiple .csv files which contains empty cell. For example:

```
Data 1, Data 2, Data 3, Data 4
Value 1, Value 2, Value 3, Value 4
<empty cell>, Value 2, Value 3, Value 4      #Trying to remove this whole row
<empty cell>, Value 2, Value 3, Value 4      #Trying to remove this whole row
Value 1, Value 2, Value 3, Value 4
```

This is what I got so far:

```
import os
import csv
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True)
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True)
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

for file in os.listdir(args["input"]):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        with open(os.path.join(args["input"],file), 'r') as infile, open(os.path.join(args["output"], file), 'w') as outfile:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(infile)
            for line in csv_reader:                                                 ///This is where I get stuck
                    with open(os.path.join(args["output"], file), 'a') as outfile:  

        outfile.close()
```

any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You can read your data into a pandas.DataFrame and then use [pandas.DataFrame.dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: tldr, so one hint first: don't do a second with block in your for loop. Rather write the line into the outputfile, but depending on a check, i.e. within an if conditional. E g. check against line starts with `','` or whatever you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty cells are represented as empty strings by the csv reader.  Empty strings have a boolean value of `False` in Python, so you can use the built-in function [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to test whether the row contains any empty cells and so whether it should be included in the output.

```
for file in os.listdir(args["input"]):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        with open(os.path.join(args["input"],file), 'r') as infile, open(os.path.join(args["output"], file), 'w') as outfile:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(infile)
            csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for line in csv_reader:
                if all(line):
                    csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Just a typo `writer.writerow(line)` ---> `csv_writer.writerow(line)` . But it works!

Answer (score 2):

You can just kill any rows with any empty cell directly upon reading:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myfile, sep=',').dropna()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python library **pandas** to manipulate your CSV as a dataframe

input file 'test_file.csv':

```
     A  B  C   D
0  1.0  3  6   9
1  NaN  4  7  10
2  2.0  5  8  11
```

Then :

```
import pandas as pd
f = 'test_file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";")

vector_not_null = df['A'].notnull()
df_not_null = df[vector_not_null]


df_not_null.to_csv ('test_file_without_null_rows.csv', index = None, header=True, sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

output file 'test_file_without_null_rows.csv':

```
     A  B  C   D
0  1.0  3  6   9
1  2.0  5  8  11
```